# Wordpress htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} SUBDOMAIN   ####UPDATE
RewriteRule . http://www.google.it [L,R]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

if I go to http://www.my-host.com/SUBDOMAIN/example-page I'm redirect to Google, How is it possible ?
It's a .htaccess file in Wordpress root folder.

Comment: Sorry I update my question....

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} SUBDOMAIN` means `SUBDOMAIN` should be part of your URL

Comment: As per this updated rule, any URI that contains `SUBDOMAIN` will be redirected to Google and that is what you're getting so what's the problem?